# Multiplier property not working properly in "toDataURL" function with cropping in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

My original size of the `canvas` is `800X700`.

I am using `clipTo` to work in a selected portion of a canvas:

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 50,
  fill: '#fff',
  width: 376,
  height: 602,
  strokeWidth: 0,
  selectable: false
});

rect.set({
    clipFor: 'mainCanvas',
});
```

I make sure all the images and text fall within this portion of the canvas.

**What I want to Do:**

I want to **scale** up this **portion of canvas** to a width and height of `1500X2400` so that it can be used for printing

I am using the below `toDataURL` function with **multiplier** as **3**

```
var imgData= canvas.toDataURL({
  format: 'png',
  width: 376,
  height: 602,
  top: 50,
  left: 100,
  multiplier: 3
});
```

But I am getting only top most portion of the image. Any solution?

---

**Update: More info about the problem**

I am using **Ubuntu 16.04** and **Fabric.js-1.6.2**

Demonstrating the problem on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7T8WC/36/)

When I click on the `enhance image` button, only the top left portion of the image is displayed.

Comment: Please add a fiddle or a snippet here with the code. a simple rect at start and end of area is enought to demonsrtate the problem. Also please include fabricjs version you are using and if you are on apple device with retina.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi : Hi,I have updated the question with a fiddle,pls take a look

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi: Hi...did you see the fiddle?

Comment: Just resize the canvas before you convert it to a dataURL. To resize and retain the original, create a new canvas 3* as big and draw the original on it 3* as big then convert that canvas to dataURL

Comment: @Blindman67 : can you pls explain as to how can I achive it given the above scenario using fabricjs?

Comment: Fabric for me is just a pain and I do not use it. This is how I do it by direct manipulation of the canvas (DOM API and 2D context API) http://jsfiddle.net/blindman67/jkkocrb4/1/ the function `makeBig` simply extracts the canvas element from the Fabric wrapper object and will not effect your Fabric structure. But surely fabric lets you resize a canvas with a disposable image?